# Can not remotely connect to Exchange server

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, exchange-2003

I have an exchange server that I can log on locally both on the PC and on the domain with the Administrator account. When ever I try to connect remotely from any other LAN PC I get an error as the image depict. This problem occured after the company had some issues[image] with the previous PC that hosted the exchange server, so they come up with the idea of take an image of the server and install it to a new one. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can ping from any pc the exchange server and from the exchange server any other pc.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing would be to ensure you have [enabled remote desktop connections to your server](https://www.petri.com/enable-remote-desktop-windows-server-2012-for-remote-administration).

You should also check any firewall rules that might block traffic on 3389/tcp and 3389/udp that might exist on either the server, or any Layer 3 devices, like routers or hardware firewalls in-between. You can also [use Telnet to test if the port is open](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality) and accessible from your own machine, or if it's being blocked along the way.

Comment: I can remote desktop from the server other computers, so probably there is no traffic block. I also enabled the remote desktop connection and added the users that are permitted to connect from the domain catalog... yet nothing happen.